# Flexslider2 Slider w/thumbnail controlNav pattern Limiting Number of thumbnails displaying

Tags: slider, flexslider

I have just implemented Flexslider2 Slider w/thumbnail controlNav Pattern.  The problem is that I have 8 images that I want to scroll through.  Right now, the thumbnails are displaying all 8 thumbnails below the main image.  I would like to limit the max number of Thumbnails displaying to 4, and then scroll the thumbnails when it gets to images 5-8.

The maxItems: 4, does not seem to be working for me.

Here is my JS:

```
<script>
$(window).load(function() {
  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: "thumbnails",
    maxItems: 4,
  });
});
</script>
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="flexslider">
             <ul class="slides">
             <li data-thumb="/Images/Products/WoodenSign/PNG/1-AMORE.PNG">
                <img src="~/Images/Products/WoodenSign/PNG/1-AMORE.PNG" />
             </li>
             <li data-thumb="/Images/Products/MagneticBoard/PNG/1-SmallProvincial_tanswirls.png">
                <img src="~/Images/Products/MagneticBoard/PNG/1-SmallProvincial_tanswirls.png" alt ="Ragged Daisy - Magnetic Board with Provincial Stain and Tan Swirls Fabric"/>
             </li>
             <li data-thumb="/Images/Products/Bench/PNG/1-BenchFullShot.png">
                <img src="~/Images/Products/Bench/PNG/1-BenchFullShot.png" alt ="Ragged Daisy - Stylish Wooden Pallet Bench"/>
             </li>
             <li data-thumb="/Images/Products/Bench/PNG/2-CabinRight.png">
                <img src="~/Images/Products/Bench/PNG/2-CabinRight.png" alt="Ragged Daisy - Stylish Wooden Pallet Bench Provincial Stain"/>
             </li>
             <li data-thumb="/Images/Products/MagneticBoard/PNG/2-vintagewhiteframe_mexicanfiesta_fullshot.png">
                <img src="~/Images/Products/MagneticBoard/PNG/2-vintagewhiteframe_mexicanfiesta_fullshot.png" alt ="Ragged Daisy - Magnetic Board with Vintage White Frame and Mexican Fiesta Fabric"/>
             </li>
             <li data-thumb="/Images/Products/MagneticBoard/PNG/3-vintagewhiteframe_tanswirls_fullshot.png">
                <img src="~/Images/Products/MagneticBoard/PNG/3-vintagewhiteframe_tanswirls_fullshot.png" alt ="Ragged Daisy - Magnetic Board with Vintage White Frame and Tan Swirls Fabric"/>
             </li>
             <li data-thumb="/Images/Products/MagneticBoard/PNG/4-TurquoiseBoard_outsideshot.png">
                <img src="~/Images/Products/MagneticBoard/PNG/4-TurquoiseBoard_outsideshot.png" alt ="Ragged Daisy - Magnetic Board with Turquoise Weathered Finish with Metal and Hooks"/>
             </li>
             <li data-thumb="/Images/Products/WoodenSign/PNG/3-LOVE.PNG">
                <img src="~/Images/Products/WoodenSign/PNG/3-LOVE.PNG" alt="Ragged Daisy - Decorative LOVE Wooden Sign"/>
             </li>
           </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: These options are present in the jquery.flexslider.js, but modifying the maxItems there to 4, doesn't seem to do anything: // Carousel Options
    itemWidth: 425,                   //{NEW} Integer: Box-model width of individual carousel items, including horizontal borders and padding.
    minItems: 0,                    //{NEW} Integer: Minimum number of carousel items that should be visible. Items will resize fluidly when below this.
    maxItems: 1,                    //{NEW} Integer: Maxmimum number of carousel items that should be visible. Items will resize fluidly when above this limit.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the Flexslider width in your css file let's say put it to `width: 400px` in the flexslider.css

```
.flexslider {
    width: 400px;
}
```

and then in your jQuery initialization of the slider define the width of the single slide, like this:

```
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
    itemWidth: 100
});
```

This is defining a width of 100px for every single slide. With this setup you should have 4 slides displayed.

Comment: I added this to the flexslider.css: .carousel li {  width: 400px; margin-right: 0px; }

Comment: Then, When I add the itemWidth: 100 to the jQuery initialization, the 100 seems to adjust the width of the main image.